# How to create a node (Circle) while the mouse is hovering over a button in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, controller, javafx-8, fxml

I have an FXML file, along with a CSS file and a Controller.java file. While the mouse is hovering over a button from the FXML file,

e.g. `fx:id="load"`

How do I create a Circle node onto the Stage?

I am currently doing this:

Note: The FXML and Controller are linked and all imports are accounted for.

```
// FXML:

<Button fx:id="load" layoutX="146.0" layoutY="307.0" mnemonicParsing="false"\
onMouseEntered="#hoverEnterLoad" onMouseExited="#hoverExitLoad"\
prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="93.0" stylesheets="@title.css" />

// Controller:

public Controller {

    @FXML private Button load;
    private Circle choose = new Circle(210.0, 278.0, 15.0, Color.TRANSPARENT);

    /**                                                                                                                                                                              
     * Shows circle                                                                                                                                                                
     */
    @FXML void hoverEnterLoad(ActionEvent event) {
        choose.setCenterX(210.0);
        choose.setCenterY(278.0);
        choose.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        choose.setRadius(15.0);
    } // hoverEnterLoad                                                                                                                                                               

    /**                                                                                                                                                                              
     * Hides circle                                                                                                                                                                
     */
    @FXML void hoverExitLoad(ActionEvent event) {
        choose.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } // hoverExitLoad

} // Controller
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

Add a transparent Circle into the FXML and edit it through the Controller.java instead of creating a new one.

```
// FXML:
// Added:

<Circle fx:id="selector" centerX="255.0" centerY="291.0" fill="TRANSPARENT" radius="5.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeType="INSIDE" />

// Controller:
// Added/Updated:

public Controller {

    @FXML private Button load;
    @FXML private Circle choose;

    /**                                                                                                                                                                              
     * Shows circle                                                                                                                                                                
     */
    @FXML void hoverEnterLoad(ActionEvent event) {
        choose.setCenterX(210.0);
        choose.setCenterY(278.0);
        choose.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        choose.setRadius(15.0);
    } // hoverEnterLoad                                                                                                                                                               

    /**                                                                                                                                                                              
     * Hides circle                                                                                                                                                                
     */
    @FXML void hoverExitLoad(ActionEvent event) {
        choose.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    } // hoverExitLoad

} // Controller
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this entirely in FXML:

```
<Button fx:id="load" layoutX="146.0" layoutY="307.0" mnemonicParsing="false"\
onMouseEntered="#hoverEnterLoad" onMouseExited="#hoverExitLoad"\
prefHeight="26.0" prefWidth="93.0" stylesheets="@title.css" />
<Circle fx:id="selector" centerX="255.0" centerY="291.0" fill="BLACK" radius="5.0" stroke="TRANSPARENT" strokeType="INSIDE" visible="${load.hover}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't just use the given hoverProperty of the Button?

```
circle.visibleProperty().bind(button.hoverProperty());
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably better. Especially if you are going to be adding plenty of circles.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private AnchorPane apMain;
    @FXML private Button load;
    Circle choose;




    @FXML void hoverEnterLoad(MouseEvent event) {
        choose = new Circle();
        choose.setCenterX(50.0);
        choose.setCenterY(50.0);
        choose.setFill(Color.BLACK);
        choose.setRadius(15.0);
        apMain.getChildren().add(choose);
        System.out.println("Mouse over button!");
    } // hoverEnterLoad                                                                                                                                                               

    /**                                                                                                                                                                              
     * Hides circle                                                                                                                                                                
     */
    @FXML void hoverExitLoad(MouseEvent event) {
        apMain.getChildren().remove(choose);
        System.out.println("Mouse no longer over!");
    } // hoverExitLoad

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
    }    

}
```